# Why need to use static MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, static

I see in multiple places that people are using static `MediaPlayer` instance when using it in a Fragment or Activity for example.
I think one reason is to make sure there will be only one active instance throughout the lifecycle so that when they need another instance, they can release the old mediaPlayer by doing something like

```
if (sMediaPlayer != null) {
    sMediaPlayer.release()
}
sMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer.create(...);
sMediaPlayer.setOnCompleteListener(__ -> {
    sMediaPlayer.release();
    sMediaPlayer = null;
}
```

Am I right? Also, are there other reason of using `static` MediaPlayer instance?
Thanks

Comment: It can cause memory leak. You can use the static mediaplayer if you use in the same context.  If you need to create a new instance, you should release a previous mediaplayer instance

Comment: @Beyazid I updated the source code. Basically this code is running in a static method in Service and I always release and nullify it after playing it. If I use a local variable instead of static var, I won't be able to release and nullify it in `onCompleteListener` because the mediaPlayer instance should be `final`. How can I use it in a static method without using static var?

Comment: I think that there is no point to use a MediaPlayer as static in an Activity/Fragment, both have a specific Android LifeCycle for initialization and so on, to have an unique shared MediaPlayer instance, one could put it in a Service, ViewModel or in a Singleton